# Downgrade PDO SQL to mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I am working on a rather old script that uses mysql_ statements. Whenever I try to issue any mysqli_ or PDO statements, things get all screwy. So I have the following code I need to re-write so that it works with the script I am reprogramming.

```
    $ids = $_POST['delete'];
    $params = array_fill(0, count($ids), "?");
    $sql = "DELETE FROM some_table WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $params) . ")";

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'user', 'pass');
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($ids);
```

The usual connections in the code I am working with look more like:

```
    include "inc/config.php";
    include "inc/funcs.php";
    @mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    @mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Unable to select database");
    include "inc/userauth.php";

    if ($_POST && isset($_POST['value'])) {

    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);

   $sql = "UPDATE oto_members SET right_sidebar = '".$value."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
   mysql_query($sql);
   }
```

So, how would I re-write the PDO code so it works with the old mysql_ style calls?

Answer (score 0):

Err, copy/paste in your code of the first example -/- pdo into the second example?

```
include "inc/config.php";
include "inc/funcs.php";
@mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
@mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Unable to select database");
include "inc/userauth.php";

if ($_POST && isset($_POST['value'])) {

$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);
 $ids = $_POST['delete'];
$params = array_fill(0, count($ids), "?");

$sql = "DELETE FROM some_table WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $params) . ")";

mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Why do yo have `$_POST['value']` in this code, as OP does not have it in the PDO code block. Also, you are doing `array_fill(0, count($ids), "?")`, so in the final query it will have placeholders `?` instead of the `id` values.

Comment: @Sean: Copied from the post from bruce to get value & id in the SQL query

Comment: but it looks like you just merged the 2 code blocks. But the OP is asking to make the 1st code block be rewritten using the `mysql_` library that is used in the 2nd code block, not a mash-up.

Comment: @Sean: The mash up is to show that it is just a copy paste action to get his code running.

Comment: Okay so this code is definitely not correct. For starters, it doesn't work. Outside of that, I don't see how this would be equivalent as $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); and  $stmt->execute($ids); are not taking place.....

Comment: `$stmt->execute($ids)` will never ever work: That is a list of ids, not an sql statement: You have to execute a piece of sql. If your original code worked from your question (your second piece without PDO), this statement should just work fine.